# How to get bash to reset variable in the next loop?

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following bash code that works correctly on the first pass of the outer loop, but breaks afterwards:

```
#!/bin/bash

cores=("a b c d e f g h")
filepath=$1 # lets call it /path/to/file/template.sql

for core in ${cores[@]}
do
  template="${core}${filepath}
  for directory in production/$core/*
  do
    bank=$(echo $directory | rev | cut -d\/ -f1 | rev)
    source apply_templates.sh $bank $template
  done
done
```

For the first outer loop, apply_templates.sh is called properly on all the banks in that core, copying the file `a/path/to/file.sql` to the right place. After all the a banks are finished, the script should be copying the file `b/path/to/file.sql to the b banks`, but instead it looks for the file `ba/path/to/file.sql`, and so on, with the last loop looking for the file `hgfedcba/path/to/file.sql`. Why does template not reassign to a new file name with the correct core but instead prepends the array element to the beginning of the existing variable?

I have tried using methods like `unset` to try and free the variable up, but it still happens. I have also tried looping over the length of cores instead of the array itself, using `${cores[$i]}` instead but the same output occurred. I have also tried building the template string over multiple lines as well. I have also tried setting template to an empty string at the end of the outer loop, so that there was nothing to concatenate with but that did not work either.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: I tried to use this site before posting as well but the changes it told me to make broke the code way worse, giving me stuff like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/path/to/file.sql` and also only touched the parts that I know work properly based on an older version of the code. The main thing it tells me is that the array in the for statement should be wrapped in quotes, causing the code to break worse than before.

Comment: going back through shellcheck again, the only changes it has me make are quoting variables to protect them, which does not help me

Comment: @MaxBrandell If shellcheck's recommendations are breaking it worse, it's likely you have multiple bugs that're partly cancelling each other out, in which case it's best to find and fix them. For example, in the code above, `cores=("a b c d e f g h")` only creates a single array entry (a string that contains spaces), and `for core in ${cores[@]}` splits that array entry on spaces (rather than iterating over the array elements properly). You should use `cores=(a b c d e f g h)` or `cores=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h")`, and `for core in "${cores[@]}"`.

Comment: `source apply_templates.sh` is going to run the code (in `apply_templates.sh`) within the context of the main script; this means any variable assignments made in `appy_templates.sh` will be available to the main script; having said that ... is there a variable named `filepath` in the `apply_tempates.sh` script? if the answer is 'yes' then I'm guessing `apply_templates.sh` is doing something like `filepath=$2` (ie, `filepath=$template`) which would manifest itself in what you're seeing (repeatedly appending `$core` on the front of `$template`)

Comment: Beyond that, I can't reproduce the problem with the code you posted here. Including a self-contained [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question would help a lot -- i.e. strip out everything not specifically needed to show the problem, so someone who doesn't have your entire directory structure available to test with can see the problem. The process of isolating the problem will probably also tell you more about what's causing it (e.g. if you remove the `source` command, does the problem go away?)

Comment: is there a reason you're sourcing `apply_template.sh` (`source apply_templates.sh $bank $template`) instead of calling as an executable script (ie, `apply_templates.sh $bank $template`)

Comment: @markp-fuso you are correct on all assertions. After changing `filepath` to a different variable name, it worked perfectly! in the future, is there anything i can do to protect the variable names across functions and prevent this? i can foresee running out of useful variable names on other projects EDIT: i see the q about executing vs sourcing, i did not write this code but there seems to be no reason for it, and upon looking up the difference it seems that `./apply_templates.sh` might have solved all my problems as well

Comment: first idea would be to make `apply_template.sh` executable (eg, `chmod 700 apply_template.sh`) and then remove the `source`, ie, call the script directly: `apply_template.sh $bank $template`; on the other hand, your latest comment mentions `variable names across functions` ... ***functions*** ?? placing code in a script and sourcing it will *behave* kinda like a function but isn't an actual function; on the other hand, if you in fact you are defining and calling a function in `apply_template.sh` then it gets more interesting ...

Comment: if you really are using a ***function*** then you can declare variables as 'local' to the function thus insuring you don't affect a variable of the same name in the parent; within a ***function*** you could add `local filepath="$2"`; but if you're not using an actual ***function*** then it gets a bit more complicated; net result is that sourcing a shell script is not the same as calling a function, so addressing your latest comment about best practice .... we'd need to know if you're dealing with a shell script or a function

Comment: yes, `./apply_templates.sh` would *execute* the script which has the benefit of running everything (inside `apply_templates.sh`) within a subshell, with one benefit being that variable assignments made in the subshell are not propagated 'up' to the parent; NOTE: I've interchanged `./apply_templates.sh` and `apply_templates.sh`, the latter assumes `.` is in your `PATH` (which it is in my env)

Comment: sorry, I meant script! new to bash, didnt even realize i wrote function. I tested the original version with ./ instead of source and it also worked perfectly. Thank you again! You've already taught me a lot